# How to stop the resize for a draggable element Jquery Ui?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a working area ,where I can drag&drop and resize my element.

```
$(objName).draggable({
    start: function (ev, ui) {$(this).css({opacity:0.3})},

    cursor:'move',
    containment: 'parent',
    snap:true,
    stop: function (ev, ui) {
        $(this).css({opacity:1});
        var pos = $(ui.helper).offset();
        console.log($(this).attr("id"));
        console.log(pos.left)
        console.log(pos.top)
    }
})
.resizable({ghost:true,

});
```

But if I start resizing it ,the size can't be fixed by the borders of working area.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is confine the Element on the resize as well as the Draggable to the working area like so

```
$(objName).draggable({
    start: function (ev, ui) {$(this).css({opacity:0.3})},

    cursor:'move',
    snap:true,
    drag: function(e, ui){
        var topRightCornerPos_x = $(this).css('left') + $(this).width();
        var bottomLeftConerPos_y = $(this).css('top') + $(this).width();

        if(topRightCornerPos_x > $(this).parent().width()){
            var maxLeft = $(this).parent().width() - $(this).width();
            $(this).css('left', maxLeft);
        }
        if(bottomLeftConerPos_y  > $(this).parent().height()){
            var maxTop = $(this).parent().height() - $9this).height();
            $(this).css('top', maxTop);
        }
    },
    stop: function (ev, ui) {
        $(this).css({opacity:1});
        var pos = $(ui.helper).offset();
        console.log($(this).attr("id"));
        console.log(pos.left)
        console.log(pos.top)
    }
})
.resizable({ghost:true,
    containment: $('#workingarea_id')
});
```

or again you can use `containment: 'parent'` in the resizable params

Comment: Is your Containment Element Fixed in size or at least has a max-size if not this could be your problem if not your going to have to right your own check i will update to show what i mean with your own check soon ok come back with a answer to the first part first ok?

Comment: i have added the check to the drag see if that works on drag for you if so copy it to the resizeable as event `resize:`